# how to apply an imageview frame with  the inclined coordinates 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, coordinates, frame

hi all upto now i know making rectangle with the CGrectmake and this rect(frame) i am using as imageview frame like UIImageView *someImage=[[uiimageview alloc]initwithframe:someRect]; now i can add an image with the frame of someRect. my problem here is when the coordinates like 
(rectangleFirstx-coordinate,tectangleFirstY-cordinate)=(10,10)

(rectangleLastx-cordinate,rectangleLasty-cordinate)=(17,7)  this, how can i give frame to the uiimageview....This is like a inclined rectangle..can any one suggest me how to apply frame through the ios library for these type of coordinates..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't very clear because a rectangle with opposite corners at (10,10) and (10,7) can be in any one of a myriad of different orientations, including one perfectly aligned along the x and y axis.

What you can certainly do is create a UIImageView of the desired size and location and then rotate it by using one of many techniques, including animation methods.

```
[UIImageView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^
{
  your_UIImageView_here.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI/180.0) * degrees);
}];
```

You can hide the UIImageView until the rotation is done and then show it.

If your question is about how to use the coordinates you provided to arrive at an angle I'd suggest that more data is needed because it is impossible to pick one of the billions of possible rectangles with corners at those two points without more information.  Once you have more data then it is pretty basic trigonometry to figure out the angle to feed into the rotation.